# near equal Cypher queries with vastly different execution times

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have one query template:

```
MATCH path=(start:LABEL)<-[:PATH*]-(global:LABEL)
WHERE all(node IN nodes(path) WHERE node:LABEL) AND
      id(start) =  id_one AND
      id(global) = id_two
RETURN start
```

depending on which ids I am entering this leads to vastly different execution times.

**How can that be and how can I ensure a low execution time for any two combination of ids?**

Comment: How many edges are in the path for the fast query time, vs how many edges are in the path for the slow query time? In other words, how long does it take you to get the mail, vs how long does it take you to travel half way around the world?

Comment: Your query is also going to return a number of rows equal to the number of paths, and ALL possible paths are going to be explored, it will not stop when it finds the first one. Is this really what you want? If you're asking if two nodes are reachable from each other with the pattern and constraints provided, you may want to use [shortestPath()](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/execution-plans/shortestpath-planning/) so on finding the first shortest path it will not continue to find additional paths

Comment: @InverseFalcon your explanation is unexpected as I figured there is only going to be one or no return value but seems quite plausible. I am not even interested in the shortest path but whether or not a path exists. Just using shortest path currently still yields a long running query in combination with a warning that exhaustive shortest path might get used. If you write an answer addressing the unexpected long runtime as well as how to use shortestPath() I'd be more than glad to accept.

Comment: It may help to add the PROFILE query plan, after expanding all elements of the plan. The (usual) advantage of shortestPath() (you'll need to add another predicate for where `start <> global`) is that it uses bfs expansion and will stop as soon as a path is found. Here's [more info](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/execution-plans/shortestpath-planning/) . The warning you mentioned is unexpected. Please confirm the query and show the query plan when you can.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution now looks like this:

```
MATCH (start:LABEL)
WHERE id(start)= {}
MATCH (end:LABEL)
WHERE id(end) = {}
MATCH path=shortestPath((start)<-[:PATH*]-(end))
RETURN DISTINCT start
```

This is quite a bit faster for me.